# why onTap of inkwell is not working ? I tried at every place but its is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter. why onTap of inkwell is not working? I tried at every place but its is not working. what am i doing wrong in this? is any alternative possible?

```
   InkWell(
     onTap: ()=>Search_box(),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: ()=>Search_box(),
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        // search wala container
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3, vertical: 0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            color: Colors.grey[400], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: (() {
            Search_box();
          }),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Search_box();
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 0, 7, 0),
                ),
              ),
               Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    Search_box();
                  },
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: ()=>Search_box(),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text("Lets search someone"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Search_box();
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: Colors.grey[600],
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 0, 7, 0),
                ),
```

Comment: what is in Search_box()?

Comment: is it a widget? if yes, flutter doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The InkWell widget must have a Material widget as an ancestor. The Material widget is where the ink reactions are actually painted

So you Should wrap the inkwell in Material widget

in  your case try this

```
    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 40,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 8),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 3, vertical: 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                              color: Colors.grey[400],
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                        child: Material(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(22.0)),
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: (() {
                              // yor method here
                            }),
                            child: Row(children: [
                                  Container(
                                    child: const Icon(
                                      Icons.search,
                                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                    ),
                                    margin:
                                        const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            3, 0, 7, 0),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Text(
                                          "Lets search someone"),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.person,
                                      color: Colors.grey[600],
                                    ),
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        3, 0, 7, 0),
                                  )
                                ]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: InkWell(
             onTap: ()=>Search_box(),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: ()=>Search_box(),
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                // search wala container
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3, vertical: 0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    color: Colors.grey[400], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: (() {
                    Search_box();
                  }),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Search_box();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.search,
                            color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          ),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 0, 7, 0),
                        ),
                      ),
                       Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            Search_box();
                          },
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: ()=>Search_box(),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Text("Lets search someone"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Search_box();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Colors.grey[600],
                          ),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 0, 7, 0),
                        ),
                      )
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
```